# Does kafka partition assignment happen across processes?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a topic with 20 partitions and 3 processes with consumers(with the same group_id) consuming messages from the topic.
But I am seeing a discrepancy where unless one of the process commits , the other consumer(in a different process) is not reading any message.
The consumers in other process do cconsume messages when I set auto-commit to true. (which is why I suspect the consumers are being assigned to the first partition in each process)

Can someone please help me out with this issue? And also how to consume messages parallely across processes ?

If it is of any use , I am doing this on a pod(kubernetes) , where the 3 processes are 3 different mules.

Comment: It's not clear how your messages are distributed within your topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commit shouldn't make any difference because the committed offset is only used when there is a change in group membership. With three processes there would be some rebalancing while they start up but then when all 3 are running they will each have a fair share of the partitions.

Each time they poll, they keep track in memory of which offset they have consumed on each partition and each poll causes them to fetch from that point on. Whether they commit or not doesn't affect that behaviour.

Autocommit also makes little difference - it just means a commit is done synchronously during a subsequent poll rather than your application code doing it. The only real reason to manually commit is if you spawn other threads to process messages and so need to avoid committing messages that have not actually been processed - doing this is generally not advisable - better to add consumers to increase throughput rather than trying to share out processing within a consumer.

One possible explanation is just infrequent polling. You mention that other consumers are picking up partitions, and committing affects behaviour so I think it is safe to say that rebalances must be happening. Rebalances are caused by either a change in partitions at the broker (presumably not the case) or a change in group membership caused by either heartbeat thread dying (a pod being stopped) or a consumer failing to poll for a long time (default 5 minutes, set by max.poll.interval.ms)

After a rebalance, each partition is assigned to a consumer, and if a previous consumer has ever committed an offset for that partition, then the new one will poll from that offset. If not then the new one will poll from either the start of the partition or the high watermark - set by auto.offset.reset - default is latest (high watermark)

So, if you have a consumer, it polls but doesn't commit, and doesn't poll again for 5 minutes then a rebalance happens, a new consumer picks up the partition, starts from the end (so skipping any messages up to that point). Its first poll will return nothing as it is starting from the end. If it doesn't poll for 5 minutes another rebalance happens and the sequence repeats.

That could be the cause - there should be more information about what is going on in your logs - Kafka consumer code puts in plenty of helpful INFO level logging about rebalances.